# How to pass variable between two queries in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

I want to put the query result from one collection in a variable and use it as input for query in another collection. The queries look like this as follows:

Query 1:

```
var ID=db.User.findOne({Name:"Ivan"}, {ID: 1});
db.Artists.find({"Listeners.ID":ID});
```

Query 2:

```
     var Friends=db.Users.find({Friends:x}); 
                 //Users.Friends is an array of interger identifier for User
     db. Artists.find({"Listeners.ID":{$in:Friends}});
```

But they all don't work. How to write the right one?

Comment: This looks remarkably similar to to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32857398/mongodb-to-assist-with-recommendations/32858673#32858673). You wouldn't possibly be expecting someone to answer so you can use it to provide your own would you? Or perhaps you are on the same team and not aware of your collegues question here.

Comment: A hint: $in requires a list of ids and `find()` returns a cursor object. Not sure why such a unresearched and simple question got up voted twice. Just printing pout the var in the console would tell you why your queries don't work.

Comment: The first query still doesn't work since it still is not in the right format

Comment: @ Sammaye, I only use $in in query 2 where the variable Friends should be a list of id, as I think.

Comment: Voting to close as a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32857398/mongodb-to-assist-with-recommendations/32858673#32858673) since it really is though it does not ask the whole question.

Comment: @Ivan: did you not read Sammaye's comment? just print your "variable" (result of the previous query) to the console, and you'll see what you need to do to make the follow-up query accept it.

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev I can't use MongoDB to try it right now. I'll appreciate it  much if you can tell me what's wrong about the queries I have wrote.

Comment: @Sammaye Please. It uses exactly the same collection names and the same field names. The question is answered and actually in the full-ness of what was intended to be asked in the first place. So I find it a very clear duplicate and am well within my rights to express that. Promoting duplicates by ignoring those facts is not what I personally deem responsible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query `db.User.findOne({Name:"Ivan"}, {ID: 1});` does not return a single value, it returns the document, reduced to the field you requested. What you get is an object, with two fields: `_id` (because you didn't explicitly exclude it) and `ID` (when it exists in the document). Your `var ID` looks like this:

```
{
    _id:ObjectId(<long hex string>),
    ID:<value>
}
```

So when you want to query by the ID value, you need to specify it:

```
db.Artists.find({"Listeners.ID":ID.ID});
```

Regarding your second query: when you use `find` instead of `findOne` you get a cursor object which can then be used to retrieve the individual documents using `cursor.next()` or `cursor.toArray()`.

Comment: So how's it if I change the first query to `db.User.findOne({Name:"Ivan"}, {_id:0, ID: 1})`?

Comment: @Ivan Then you get an object with just one field: `{ ID: <value> }`.

Comment: So the answer would be the same as `db.Artists.find({"Listeners.ID":ID.ID});`?

Comment: @Ivan yes, it would not change anything.

Comment: How's it if the ID is not a single field, but an array of ids? For example, I change the first query to `var IDs=db.Artists.findOne({"Tags.Creater":{$in:[x]}}, {_id:0, ID:{$slice:1}, ID:1})`. Can I still use `db.Artists.find({"Listeners.ID":IDs.ID});` ?

Comment: @Ivan when you have an array, you need to use the operators $in or $all, depending on what you want to do.

Comment: So the answer would be `db.Artists.find({"Listeners.ID":{$in: IDs.ID}});` am I correct?